# Firestore "too many index entries for entity" error: Which index?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

We hit the "too many index entries for entity" error:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: too many index entries for entity
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:195:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

It seams I have to exempt a field from automatic indexing. But how do I know which field? The document has a lot of data with nested maps. Here is an example of the document:

```
{products: {
            "p1": {id: "p1", :name "Product1", :group "g1"},
            "p2": {id: "p2", :name "Product2", :group "g2"},
            "p3": {id: "p2", :name "Product3", :group "g3"}
           }}
```

Any suggestions which field would cause the error?

Comment: "Any suggestions which field would cause the error?" The problem comes from the fact that you have nested maps, see https://firebeast.dev/tips/too-many-index-entries-for-entity. You are the only one that can decide which exemption to potentially declare.

Answer (score 1):

Override field `products` in `firestore.indexes.json`:

```json
    {
     "fieldOverrides": [
        {
            "collectionGroup": "menu",
            "fieldPath": "products",
            "indexes": []
        }
    ]}
```